# Is there a way to export a table with the time(7) datatype using gsqlcmd?

Tags: sql-server, command-line

I am using the gsqlcmd command-line tool to read and export SQL files. I am able to do so, but not if one the tables I'm exporting has a time(7) datatype column. It doesn't recognize this type. How do I get it to recognize it?

I use this command:
`gsqlcmd my_database_name "select * from table_name"`

When I execute this command for a table that doesn't have this type, it displays the columns and data in the command line.

When I include this datatype, it gives me this error:

> Execution error: Unknown SQL type - SS_TIME_EX.

Comment: Here's a link to the documentation: [link](https://www.gsqlcmd.com/gsqlcmd/getting-started.htm)

Comment: I suggest you post your question to their support organization. And their documentation is pretty thin - which is not a good sign. If you would rather not wait for them to either fix this error (or add support for this datatype), you can consider casting the value to one that is supported. What datatype to use? Good question. Casting to time with less precision or even varchar? Alternatively, use a different ETL tool. bcp perhaps?

Comment: @SMor Ah okay. I just emailed them, but I will most likely just use another datatype. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Support suggested that I was probably using the wrong provider in my connection string- I needed to use the .NET SqlClient Data Provider. It reads the time datatype now.